# Statistical guarantees for factor models( higher-rank case)

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Consider the following statistical estimation problem:
We observe a realization of a random matrix $Y$ of the form $Y = X° + W$, where $X°$ is an unknown $m\times n$ rank $k$ matrix and $W$ is a matrix with iid entries drawn from the standard Gaussian distribution $\mathcal N(0,1)$.
The goal is to compute an estimate $X$ that is as close as possible to $X°$.

As we have seen, the maximum likelihood estimator $X_{\text{mle}}(Y)$ has the following form
$X_{\text{mle}}(Y) = \text{argmin}_X\{||X - Y||^2_F,\;\text{rank}(X) \leq  k\}$.

Prove the following approximation guarantee for this estimator
$$E||X°-X(Y)||^2_F≤kO(n + m)$$

And we know that the spectral norm $||W||$ of $W$ satisfies
$E(|| W||^2) \leq O(n+m)$.

Actually I know how to prove the rank-1 case, but how can I adapt the proof?
Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you confirm that the bound on the spectral norm of $W$ is $E(|| W||^2) \leq O(n+m)$ ? What you had written is ambiguous.

Comment: yeah I am sure that E||W||2 ≤ O(n+m)